# Are there cases in which trailing-return-type syntax in lambda cannot be avoided?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, trailing-return-type

In relation to a previous question ([Is it possible to return an object of type T by reference from a lambda without using trailing return type syntax?](/q/40977730)), I was wondering if there is any other significant case or example in which *trailing-return-type* syntax, when using lambdas, can **not** be avoided.

Comment: When you want to return a (temporary) object without giving a type. Like `return {a, b, c};`

Comment: When you want to return a reference to an object.

Comment: @SergeyA I wrote: can **not** be avoided

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, you are right but the case you mentioned is the same one of the above related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++14, a bit contrived example is the use of sfinae in combination with a generic lambda:

```
[](auto &&arg)
-> decltype(arg.f(), void())
{ /* do whatever you want */ }
```

Anyway one could argue that a `static_assert` suffices:

```
[](auto &&arg) {
    static_assert(has_metod_f<std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>>::value, "!");
    /* do whatever you want */
}
```

Where `has_method_f` is the common detector idiom.
Anyway, imagine a case where you want to construct a composed functor starting from a bunch of lambdas:

```
#include<utility>
#include<iostream>

template<typename...>
struct Base;

template<typename Func, typename... Others>
struct Base<Func, Others...>: Func, Base<Others...> {
    Base(Func func, Others... others)
    : Func{std::move(func)}, Base<Others...>{std::move(others)...}
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(int, Args&&... args)
    -> decltype(Func::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        Func::operator()(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(char, Args&&... args) {
        Base<Others...>::operator()(0, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template<>
struct Base<> {
    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&...) {
        std::cout << "fallback" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename... Ops>
struct Mixin: Base<Ops...> {
    Mixin(Ops... ops)
        : Base<Ops...>{std::move(ops)...}
    {}

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args&&... args) {
        return Base<Ops...>::operator()(0, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

struct T { void f() {} };
struct U {};

int main() {
    auto l1 = [](auto &&arg) -> decltype(arg.f(), void()) {
        std::cout << "accept T" << std::endl;
    };

    auto l2 = [](U) {
        std::cout << "accept U" << std::endl;
    };

    Mixin<decltype(l1), decltype(l2)> mixin{std::move(l1), std::move(l2)};
    mixin(T{});
    mixin(U{});
    mixin(0);
}
```

In this case, a `static_assert` would prevent the compilation and it is not the expected result.
On the other side, the trailing return type can be used to enable sfinae directly on the lambdas with the help of their wrappers.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that another case is when there is type inconsistency between differents returns.

A silly example

```
std::function<long(int)> f 
    = [](int v) -> long { if ( v ) return v; else return 0L; };
```

Obviously you can avoid it if you avoid inconsistency so I don't know if it's significant.

Comment: @skypjack - right; exactly what I mean with "you can avoid it if you avoid inconsistency"; take in count that the example is very very silly.

Comment: I see, but please let me say that it doesn't answer the question. It can be easily avoided in this case.

Comment: @skypjack - franckly, I don't know if answer to the question; as I've written, "I don't know if it's significant"; I let the OP respond to this question.