# Generic lambda, inheritance and trailing return type: is this valid code?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, language-lawyer

I was trying to reply to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41110251/4987285) and I found some difficulties while playing with lambdas and inheritance. Consider the following, minimal example:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
struct Base: Func {
    Base(Func func): Func{func} {}

    template<typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Args... args)
    -> decltype(Func::operator()(args...), void()) {
        Func::operator()(args...);
    }
};

int main() {
    auto l = [](auto &&) {};
    Base<decltype(l)> mixin{l};
    mixin(0);
}
```

GCC 6.1 compiles it, clang 4.0 crashes (see https://godbolt.org/z/6Gz5s66h5).
Note that both compile just fine using the following definition:

```
auto l = [](int) {};
```

Is this valid code or I'm doing something that is not allowed by the standard?

---

I've reported this as [LLVM bug 31356](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/30704), though I'd still like to know whether my code is correct.

Comment: If a compiler crashes, it's a bug. Are there any other options?

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough. I wanted to know if the code is valid actually. :-)

Comment: May I suggest you edit the *"is this a bug?"* part out? I feel like it distracts from your actual question ("is this code valid").

Comment: @BaummitAugen Just done. Removed the word _bug_ from the question.

Comment: @n.m. if you compile an ill-formed program, crashing (with an ice message) meets the requirments of printing a diagnostic.  Now so does `print " \n"`, but I think a crash is a better QOI.  ;)

Comment: Looks valid to me.

Comment: @Yakk yes but it's still a bug.

Comment: posted a new question as a follow-on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117450/non-const-method-on-derived-class-calls-const-method-on-base-class-should-this

Comment: Still, congratulations for crashing Clang ;)

Comment: @Quentin I was trying to do it for a long time... :-D

Answer (score 0):

The bug report you've opened [has been resolved](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/30704#issuecomment-1675938760) in clang 14. Note that if a compiler crashes, this is *always* a bug, and not your fault.

> Is this valid code or I'm doing something that is not allowed by the standard?

Yes, it is valid C++14 code, and more recent versions of clang allow it too. The only difference between `[](auto &&) {};` and `[](int) {}` is that one lambda has a call operator that's a member function template, not just a member function.

That should not prevent you from inheriting from the lambda's closure type, or anything else you're doing in your code.

#### Workaround

The ICE seems to occur when parsing `-> decltype(Func::operator()(args...), void())`. You could instead write:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
auto operator()(Args... args) -> decltype(std::declval<Func&>()(args...), void())
{
    Func::operator()(args...);
}
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/8Y8W8cYjc) using clang 13*

Answer (score -1):

Just if you need a solution for clang - the following code should work with clang

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
struct Base : F
{
  Base (F f) : F {f} {}

  template <typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) operator () (Args&&... args)
  {
    std::cout << "(";
    F::operator () (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
    std::cout << ")" << std::endl;
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  auto l = [] (auto && i) {
    std::cout << i;
  };
  Base<decltype(l)> mixin {l};
  mixin (0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the name `mixin` strongly suggests that more work is to be done before and/or after forwarding to `Func::operator()`.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear for me. Modified the answer to address this.